# DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB touchscreen miscalibration

Tags: ubuntu, touch, calibration

I have a problem with my PenMount USB touchscreen in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
From the center (where it is precise) to the sides, the touchscreen becomes increasingly imprecise (both in X and Y directions). So the mouse pointer never reaches the edges by the touch.

After installing Ubuntu the touch control was inverted (x and Y), but I was able to fix that with a udev rule (/etc/udev/rules.d/99-calibration.rules):

`ATTRS{name}=="DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB", ENV{LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX}="-1 0 1 0 -1 1"`

But the described miscalibration still exists.

I tried to calibrate the touchscreen with the command:
`./xinput_calibrator --output-type xorg.conf.d`

The file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf with the output of the command above does not affect the behavior of the touch panel. What's more, if I enter an obviously incorrect value into the file, I don't find any error in the Xorg.log.

It looks as if the driver of the touch panel would calculate the pointer position to a lower resolution than the existing one.
How to tell the driver the actual screen resolution?

Specs:
DIALOGUE INC PenMount USB Touchscreen
Ubuntu 22. 04 LTS Server with Xorg

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188624/trouble-with-xinput-calibrator-on-a-toughbook-cf-19
or here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310691/touchscreen-calibration-fails-on-ubuntu-20-04-pixelbook.
After the execution of the following install/uninstall commands :

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

the X-Server has read the already existent /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf. This file obviously "tells" the driver what the screen resolution is. The calibration works fine.

Comment: Btw: in this case, is the rule for LIBINPUT_CALIBRATION_MATRIX in the file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-calibration.rules not necessary. xinput_calibrator also inverts the x and y coordinates.